# GitHub Desktop - No Windows opening on Mac El Capitan 10.11.1

Tags: macos, github, osx-elcapitan

I seem to be having this really weird issue where Github Desktop doesn't open any windows on the mac.

Upon setup I had a window to sign in and choose my repo but after that set up no window shows up

Anyone else had an issue like this?
Is there a way I can provide log/error files?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the same problem I had, for which I contacted GitHub Support. They suggested deleting GitHub Desktop and downloading a fresh copy (e.g., 222 in my case), then unarchiving it with the Mac Archive Utility instead of a third-party archiver (I had used WinZip). This resolved the windowing problem I had.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and I resolved it by simply unzipping a fresh copy of GitHub Desktop.

I used "TheUnarchiver app" (https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12) for this, (but any unpacking software should to the trick).